# Magento 2 : ERROR: Call to a member function getTelephone() on null

Tags: magento2, event-observer

**Getting error**

> [2021-09-06 16:23:17] report.ERROR: Call to a member function
> getTelephone() on null {"exception":"[object]
> (GraphQL\Error\Error(code: 0): Call to a member function
> getTelephone() on null at
> /var/www/magento/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Error/Error.php:174,
> Error(code: 0): Call to a member function getTelephone() on null at

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($order->getCustomerEmail());
    $telephone = $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone();
}
```

**any way to fix it ?**

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: This is because $order->getShippingAddress() is not an object and $order->getShippingAddress() is null while it must be an object. Can you please print_r($order->getShippingAddress()->getData()) and see what data you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$telephone = $order->getShippingAddress() ? $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone() : false;
```